# Correct way to change color of a combobox in QML

Tags: qt, qml

What is the correct way to change the color in a combobox?

I know that i can do this:

```
ComboBox {
    background: Rectangle {
        color:"blue"
    }
}
```

and it turns like this:
[image]

but then i lose the focus border (at least it appears when i do tab to go from one control to another) that is normal to appear in the combobox:

[image]

What is the solution?

Comment: All that concerns the control customization is described in detail in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-combobox). Another way is [Control.palette](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-controls2-control.html#palette-prop). Try to find a suitable property to change the background. Check the control [source](https://github.com/qt/qtquickcontrols2/blob/5.11/src/imports/controls/ComboBox.qml#L93) to see how the default style is used.

Comment: @folibis nice that seems to work! thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed by `folibis` we can find the answer to do that in the [source](https://github.com/qt/qtquickcontrols2/blob/5.11/src/imports/controls/ComboBox.qml#L93) 
i did the following:

```
ComboBox {
id:comboBoxCustom
    background: Rectangle {
        color:"white"
        border.width: parent && parent.activeFocus ? 2 : 1
        border.color: parent && parent.activeFocus ? comboBoxCustom.palette.highlight : comboBoxCustom.palette.button
    }
}
```